# Prevent user from adding more values to Autocomplete once a value length limit is reached

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an autocomplete component set up like below. I was wondering if it was possible to prevent users from adding any chips once the number of chips reaches a certain length (e.g. 10).

So you would still be able to delete the chips, but no longer able to add anymore once you have 10 chips. I've tried using the validate function, but couldn't get it to work.

```
<Controller
  name={keyValue}
  control={control}
  defaultValue={defaultValue || []}
  disabled={disabled}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      multiple
      options={options}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          {...params}
          label={label}
          error={field.value?.length > 10}
          helperText={field.value?.length > 10 && "Error Message"}
        />
      )}
      {...field}
      value={field.value || []}
      onChange={(e, val) => {
        field.onChange(val);
      }}  
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: which component library you are using?

Comment: @DineshMsd React material ui

Answer (score 0):

Check if the length of selected chips is less than 10. Change your onChange like below:

```
onChange={(e, val) => {
            if (field.value.length < 10) {
              field.onChange(val);
            }
          }}
```